# Subsonic 3 Active Record Testing

Tags: unit-testing, activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3

Using the new built in testing for Active Record (set "Test" as the connection string) I've hit a problem performing an update.

The code I'm testing pulls an existing object out of the database, makes some changes to it, and then saves it.

```
public void SaveProduct(string productId) {

var dbProduct = Model.Generated.Product.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ProductID == productId);

dbProduct.Description = "Description";
dbProduct.Price = "Price";

dbProduct.Save();

}
```

To test this, I'm creating a new list of products, with one product in it.

```
_dbProducts = new List<Product>
                      {
                          new Product
                              {
                                  ProductID = "XXX0001"
                              }
                      };
```

Then I set up the test (fake).

```
Product.Setup(_dbProducts)
```

call the save method

```
repository.SaveProduct("XXX0001");
```

The problem is I'm getting the following error message...

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>       at SubSonic.Repository.TestRepository`1.Add(T item, IDataProvider provider)
>       at Model.Generated.Product.Add(IDataProvider provider) in ActiveRecord.cs: line 708
>       at Model.Generated.Product.Save(IDataProvider provider) in ActiveRecord.cs: line 721
>       at Model.Generated.Product.Save() in ActiveRecord.cs: line 715
>       at Subsonic.PDAJobRepository.SaveProduct() in ProductRepository.cs: line 46
>       at Tests.ProductRepository.When_Saving_Product.Setup() in When_Saving_Product.cs: line 44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ick - can you log this issue for me:
http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues

That's an oversite.